# taking an input from a user, adding elements of the string together

Tags: python

so I take a user input in a loop seen below

```
mail_list = []
x = 0
while x >= 0:
    user_input = input('enter first name, last name, ID, and email domain: ')
    mail_list.append(user_input)
    if user_input == 'done':
        break
```

so it is supposed to add the first name, last name, and email domain together to make a full email address. not sure if lists are the best path to go or splicing the spring. The problem I ran into when trying to just splice it would only use 'done' as the last input so I assumed adding it to a list would be the best path. just lost

Comment: Do you want the user to input all the information at once?  It isn't really clear what you are trying to do since in your code you really don't do anything

Comment: Are you expecting something like `email = first_name + '.' + last_name + '@gmail.' + domain`

Answer (score 0):

> *Are you expecting something like `email = first_name + '.' + last_name + '@gmail.' + domain`*

I'll suppose this comment by Gautam Chettiar is right.

---

At this point you have `mail_list` which contains all the parts of the email address, you can join this manually.

```
email = mail_list[0] + '.' + mail_list[1] + '@gmail.' + mail_list[2]
```

This is not an elegant solution, but if you really don't want to create more variables or (even better) to input all the address at once, I think this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you might want something like:

```
mail_list = []
while True: # use an infinite loop
    user_input = input('enter first name, last name, ID, and email domain: ')

    # check if we're done before doing anything else
    if user_input == 'done':
        break

    # try to split the string into 4 chunks
    try:
        first, last, ID, domain = map(str.strip, user_input.split(','))
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid format, please try again')
        continue

    # do something with the input
    # here creating a first.last@domain string
    mail_list.append(f'{first}.{last}@{domain}')
print(mail_list)
```

Example:

```
enter first name, last name, ID, and email domain: first, last, ABC, example.org
enter first name, last name, ID, and email domain: first2, last2, DEF
Invalid format, please try again
enter first name, last name, ID, and email domain: first2, last2, DEF, example.org
enter first name, last name, ID, and email domain: done
['first.last@example.org', 'first2.last2@example.org']
```